# subscription receipt not received after reinstall app

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store, auto-renewable

I am implement renewing subscription in my application.

When I purchase pack then I get receipt from app store by following code

```
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
```

Question : When I reinstall my app. I get **nil** from **receipt** In iPhoneX(11.4.1) But working fine in iPod(9.3.5)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the same App Store account on both devices? Is this happening in Sandbox mode or production?

Comment: Are you using the same App Store account on both devices? - Yes .... Is this happening in Sandbox mode or production? -  Sandbox mode

Comment: On physical devices, you should have a receipt file for a subscription that's shared across your App Store account (you won't see receipts in simulator). This may be an issue with Sandbox mode.

Comment: I also assumed this is an issue with Sandbox mode.